# Disable a default theme

Tags: theming

I want to disable the default theme in my Drupal 7.5 system installation instance. How can I do this? I can't find a *Disable* link using the Creative Responsive theme version 7.x-1.1.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal requires that one theme must always be set as default. Further, you cannot disable a theme that is currently set as default.

Best bet would be for you to enable another theme, set it as default, then disable the one you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal will require at least one theme to be set as default. You will need to setup another theme as default and then you will be able to disable this theme.